# Adding a 'network' USB printer

Tags: networking, xubuntu, printing

I have a HP Deskjet 1050a printer, hence the 'network' in the title.  Its a bog standard USB home printer.
I have it attached to my router (has a USB port in it). I have got it connected and working to with Win8 PC and also a MacBook Air.  Can't seem to get it to add as a printer to my Xubuntu laptop(s).

It doesn't get detected automatically (not an actual network printer) and i've tried multiple options to get it working.  It seems to add it but when printing a test page its saying the printer isn't connected.
Ping works fine so it can see it, just can't add it as a printer.

With Win8 I had to create a port with the IP of the printer (192.168.1.253 in this case), is there an Ubuntu alternative to do this?

Comment: "No printer was found at that address"

Comment: what router are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT! The "lpr" got me thinking.

System Settings > Printers > Add a new printer > Network Printer (Drop down) > LPD/LPR Host or Printer. 
Put the IP "192.168.1.253", then put a print queue name "queueTG582n" and bingo, one beautiful Ubuntu test page!

The router is a Technicolor TG582n, so not the most advanced one in the world.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working by whatever means.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go to System Settings > Printers > Add a new printer. Select Network Printer and use the URI of:

```
ipp://192.168.1.253:631/lpr
```

Then select the brand and model of your printer. In most cases, the default driver works well. Print a test page. In a few cases, you will need to use ipp14:// instead of ipp://.

Comment: Didn't work.  With ipp:// i get "The printer is not responding.  With ipp14:// I get "unable to connect".

Comment: Tried a few other combinations:
- lpd://192.168.1.253:631.   Seems to connect ok, printer state goes from "Processing - Copying print data" to "The printer is in use".  Take off the port 631 and its goes through the processing then says "Idle - Connected to Printer"