# connecting printer to usb port on router

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, hp

I have a printer hp deskjet F2280 that is connected to the USB port of zyxel vmg5313-b30a router. In the print server settings of the router I get the message "To use the print server, define a network printer with a URL http://192.168.5.1:631/printers/Printer."
This URL I use in Windows when connecting to a printer and works without any problems. When I try to use the printer with laptop (Ubuntu gnome 16.04.2 LTS) I get the notification "Printing completed", but nothing happens.
Drivers I used are: "hpcups 3.16.3".
Printer state: "Idle - Rendering completed"

when I go to Ink / tonner levels under printer properties, I get:
Printer 'HP Deskjet-F2200' 'cups-ipp-conformance-failure-report'. 
Printer 'HP Deskjet-F2200' 'cups-IPP-missing-printer-is-accepting-jobs'.
Printer 'HP Deskjet-F2200' 'cups-IPP-missing-printer-state-reasons ".
Printer 'HP Deskjet-F2200' 'cups-IPP-missing-cancel-job'.
Printer 'HP Deskjet-F2200' 'cups-IPP-missing-validate-job'.
Printer 'HP Deskjet-F2200' 'cups-IPP-missing-job-id'.
Does someone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: Just a stab in the dark here. Please try instead: `ipp://192.168.5.1:631/printers/Printer`

Comment: @chili555 I already tried it. Got the same result. Also I tried using the "AppSocket/HP JetDirect".

Comment: I have [a similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/997828/printing-using-a-hp-deskjet-1000-j110a-connected-via-usb-to-a-starbridge-1531-ro) and found [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514350/adding-a-network-usb-printer) to a similar problem
I say similar because the router and printer make and model differ. That said in all 3 cases (yours, the one i found and mine) the printers are hp deskjets as far as i understand that answer using the lpd/lpr host option with the ip of the router and a "queue name" solves the issue
currently don't get what the queue name is since i keep g

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a 'network' USB printer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514350/adding-a-network-usb-printer)