# How do I use router as print server?

Tags: xubuntu, printing, router, hplip

I want to use the usb ports from my router. I tried to use 2 routers: the Archer C7 and US Robotics 5464 (USR 5464), but I can't get it to work under Xubuntu 16.04. In Windows 10 both routers work. First the Archer C7. First let me describe how it works in Windows 10. Through the TPlink software tool. In Xubuntu I tried it with disabled firewall in cups. All protocols.. Ip-adress in same range as other pc's. In router the firewall, nat and dhcp are off. Then the USR. In the end I tried it with a utp cable connected with one pc, without WAN and wifi and firewalls and the standard http://192.168.2.1:1631/printers/My_Printer (and other protocols too of course). The USR technician says that it is impossible to get it to work.

From this website https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html I tried adding several things in the cupsd.conf but the errorfile says I am doing it wrong.

The printers I have tried are HP Deskjet 9670 and HP PSC 2355. HPLIP says something about the firewall (mdns and slp), but the firewalls are disabled. If I connect the printers directly or through the NAS I have no problem printing.

Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: I use an Archer C7 and an HP M201dw printer, although it is connected by ethernet. Have you installed the package `hplip`? In my case, the printer and URI were auto-detected and it works perfectly.

Comment: I overlooked your answer because it is a comment (if I am correct?). I took another pc. Installed hplip. Then I have to use hp-doctor. It says I have to open ports for mdns and slp in the firewall, but the firewall of the router is off and also disabled for my pc (sudo ufw status)..

Comment: Where did you get port 1631 in your question? The usual CUPS port is 631, not 1631. Does it help if you change it?

Comment: When I use HPlip device manager, connection type network, I also get the popup with the firewall message about mdns and slp. And see http://hplipopensource.com/node/375. Port 631 didn't help for the USR. For the Archer router I guess it is just http://192.168.0.20 without additional port. Because of the first comment I am now trying with the Archer again..

Comment: When I choose Add a printer I can add an url, but after having chosen the right hp driver it gives a cups error "client-error-not-possible". Maybe that is because I have tried to change the cupsd.conf (see top message).

Comment: Also when I choose Add a printer on tab Server I can choose Connect. There I can choose between "var/run/cups/cups.sock" of "localhost". Should I choose the first or does if not matter?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the file and the changes you made. Normally, one need do nothing! Doesn't `hplip` attemt to autodetect the printer? Mine, connected by ethernet, detects: `hp:/net/HP_LaserJet_Pro_M201dw?ip=192.168.0.5` I think you are changing too many things at once.

Comment: Same problem with someone else 3 days ago: http://askubuntu.com/questions/898077/connecting-printer-to-usb-port-on-router

Comment: How do I solve the phplip errors?

Comment: In the Archer C7, under USB settings > Print Server, is the status *Online*?  Also, please run: `hp-check`. It produces a log, hp-check.log. Please paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Before I paste anything,I wrote TPlink an e-mail and the answer is: "The device is only compatible with Windows." Is this the truth? @chili555 I cannot connect to the Archer anymore because DHCP of the router is off (with Linux it is possible but I don't know how), but before I switched it off (and the firewall) I saw that said printer Online.

Comment: It is not the truth. I have only Ubuntu machines in the house and an iPad. I configure my Archer C7 router using the browser interface from Ubuntu. What they meant to say, in my opinion, was that they haven't the resources or knowledge to support all the various flavors of Linux and therefore have no suggestions. Why did you turn off DHCP? It is possible but quite cumbersome to set static IP addresses but trivial with DHCP.