# printing using a HP Deskjet 1000 j110a connected via USB to a Starbridge 1531 Router using Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, printing, hp

I'm using a Starbridge 1531 router which has a single USB port. The printer is a HP Deskjet 1000 j110a connected to that USB port. I do not have admin access to the printer. I wish to print from this printer but I don't have the printer name.

I have scoured the Internet for a way to set it for the specific router and I have found [this](https://fccid.io/VYJ-1531/User-Manual/user-manual-1402703#pf1b) or more specificly [the settings I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDX41.png)
according to those settings I need the printer name set up in router but attemping to do that seems to require admin access...

I've also tried typing `http://192.168.1.1:631/printers` in the hope it would be listed...

I've also tried finding it using the hplib GUI but it doesn't seem to find it.

Using the normal dash>printers>add does seem to find the printer on `192.168.1.1:631` but when I attempt to print a test page it stops at "stopped rendering complete"

Is there a way to find the full address of the printer without needing admin access?

UPDATE:after failing to actually find the network address, i finally went to customer service and got the address.

By using the ipp protocol via http the printer jobs do get completed! But the printer doesn't exactly print
By using LPD/LPR host it show the message "printer in use"
meanwhile HPLIB doesn't detect the printer at all.....

I should note that the printer works fine when connected directly to my ubuntu 16.04 laptop

UPDATE 2:After digging some more i found this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html). I tried editing `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`.

first i added http://192.168.1.1:631 to the listen addresses and i got the error `Unable to open listen socket for address 192.168.1.1:631 - Cannot assign requested address.`
then i edited it to http://192.168.1.1:631/printers/HPDESKJET1000 and i got the error `Hostname lookup for "http://192.168.1.1" failed.
Bad Listen address http://192.168.1.1:631/printers/HPDESKJET1000 at line 18.`

i have now tried inputting `hp:net/HP_Deskjet_1000_J110_series?ip=192.168.1.1:631/printers/HPDESKJET1000` [based on this](http://www.mygnulinux.com/?p=1192) directly and hplib now delivers messages about starting the job and completing the job......despite not actually completing the job and the printer status still being stuck on "idle - rendering complete"

Comment: Perhaps the router publishes the printer address via `mDNS` or something. The logs will tell you. In a terminal window, do `journalctl --follow | tee journalctl.log `. Then power-cycle the router or unplug/replug your ethernet cable. In either case, wait 60 seconds between OFF and ON.

Comment: the printer is connected via usb so i unplug/replugged that it doesn't seem to appear

Comment: If the IP address of the router is, in fact, 192.168.1.1, I think I'd simply try adding it as you specify and I suspect it will work. Typically, printers attached to the USB port of the router can be located at <IP_address_of_router>:631.

Comment: yes i tried that and i came up till print test page
when i attempted that and monitored the status i stopped after rendering the output

Comment: uh no idea what changed but after messing with the settings in the cups web interface i managed to make it to "connected to printer" which persists untill "processing - unable to get printer status"

Comment: i've updated the question

Comment: i tried adding it like @AndrewK and i get "printer in use" message now

Answer (score 0):

You could try `nmap` to find all IP Addresses in your local network and search for the IP Address that has an common printer port opened. (I think 9100 is a common port for printer). You need to run `nmap NETWORK_IP/SUBMASK` as shown [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=840569#p840569).

Comment: i've updated the question now that i went to customer service

Comment: What is the ip address now? And I assume you are using CUPS for managing the printer. Is the printer listed in the Web interface of CUPS? The web interface is normally on localhost:631.

Comment: the ip is http://192.168.1.1:631/printers/HPDESKJET1000 its not automatically detected but when added manually the printjobs reported as complete tho printer doesn't actually print

Comment: If you go to that link from your printer, what is in the "Connection" line? If you open a document and open the print window, does it list your printer? As shown [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS/Troubleshooting#CUPS:_Job_is_shown_as_complete_but_the_printer_does_nothing), it might be an issue with the driver. Did you try setup your printer with `hp-setup`? I think this should normally install the driver for you. (You probably need root access to find the printer)

Comment: i can't load that page strange enough and hp-setup doesn't find it at all.
Connected directly via USB it does find it and and prints normally.

Comment: that link you gave me seems to say that i need to download the firmware to the printer would this effect other computers using it?
the printers works fine via network on my brother's win 8 pc....

Comment: Can you access the [CUPS Webinterface](http://localhost:631)? If so, can you access the [printer details](http://localhost:631/printers/HPDESKJET1000)? Is an open jetdirect port listed when you type `nmap 192.168.1.1/24 | grep -E "report|jetdirect|910"`? (Assuming that this is your submask and network ip) If so, what is the ip above the open port text? And the output of `lpstat -s`?

Comment: Ok, it is not about having access to the [printer details](http://localhost:631/printers/HPDESKJET1000). But you need to have valid informations on the website. (Nothing in curly brackets)

Comment: wait what? what do you mean?
and sorry for the late reply the output for lpstat -s for the printer in question is 
`system default destination: HP-Deskjet-1000-j110
device for HP-Deskjet-1000-j110: ipp://192.168.1.1:631/printers/HPDESKJET1000
device for HP-Deskjet-1000-J110-series: hp:/usb/Deskjet_1000_J110_series?serial=CN29O29KPN05D2
` hmm interesting

Comment: the information listed at the printer details is 
`Description:HP Deskjet 1000 j110
Location: HomeWifi
Driver: HP Deskjet 1000 j110 Series, hpcups 3.17.11 (color)
Connection: ipp://192.168.1.1:631/printers/HPDESKJET1000
Defaults: job-sheets=none, none media=na_letter_8.5x11in sides=one-sided`

interestingly the printer is not listed when using `nmap 192.168.1.1/24 | grep -E "report|jetdirect|910"`

Comment: if i do `nmap 192.168.1.1/24 | grep -E "report|631` i do get `631/tcp open  ipp`

Comment: After digging some more i found this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html). I tried editing `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`.

first i added http://192.168.1.1:631 to the listen addresses and i got the error `Unable to open listen socket for address 192.168.1.1:631 - Cannot assign requested address.`
then i edited it to http://192.168.1.1:631/printers/HPDESKJET1000 and i got the error `Hostname lookup for "http://192.168.1.1" failed.
Bad Listen address http://192.168.1.1:631/printers/HPDESKJET1000 at line 18.`